# C++ misuse of template or problems of compilers string literal comparison with template

Tags: c++, string, templates, comparison, literals

When I am reading "C++ Primer" (4th Edition) Chapter 16.1, there is a simple template demo:

```
// implement strcmp-like generic compare function
// returns 0 if the values are equal, 1 if v1 is larger, -1 if v1 is smaller
template <typename T>
int compare(const T &v1, const T &v2)
{
    if (v1 < v2) return -1;
    if (v2 < v1) return 1;
        return 0;
}
```

the invocation in main function:

```
int main ()
{
    // T is int;
    // compiler instantiates int compare(const int&, const int&)
    cout << compare(1, 0) << endl;
    // T is string;
    // compiler instantiates int compare(const string&, const string&)
    string s1 = "hi", s2 = "world";
    cout << compare(s1, s2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I made several modifications over this piece of code:

```
//----------------------------test.cpp start----------------
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
int myCompare(const T &v1, const T &v2){
    cout << v1 << " " << ((v1 > v2) ? (">") : ((v1 < v2) ? ("<") : ("="))) << " " << v2 << endl;
    return (v1 > v2) ? (1) : ((v1 < v2) ? (-1) : 0);
};

int main(void) {
    int iRes;
    cout << "String 1 : " << "A"<<endl;
    cout << "String 2 : " << "a"<<endl;
    iRes = myCompare("A", "a");
    cout << "A " << ((iRes == 1) ? (">") : ((iRes == (-1)) ? ("<") : ("="))) << " a" << endl;
    return 0;
};
//----------------------------test.cpp end----------------
```

there is a problem when I compile and run it:

under VS2008, it gives:

```
String 1 : A
String 2 : a
A > a
A > a
```

under g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, it gives:

```
String 1 : A
String 2 : a
A < a
A < a
```

the correct answer is `**A<a**`.

However, when I comment out the following:

```
cout << "String 1 : " << "A" << endl;
cout << "String 2 : " << "a" << endl;
```

under VS2008, it gives:

```
String 1 : A
String 2 : a
A < a
A < a
```

under g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, it gives:

```
String 1 : A
String 2 : a
A > a
A > a
```

the compile command is as following:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -Wall -O0
```

I want to know why this could happen? Is the problem (A?B:C) expression that I have used incorrectly? It seems that my code is correct. It has bothered me for days. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Case Closed!

I replaced the myCompare() invocation by the following:

```
iRes=myCompare(static_cast<string>("A"), static_cast<string>("a"));
```

It works. No matter how I change the context, it always gives the right answer. I should have been aware that I am comparing two `const char*`, I give it a try just to be sure about it.

The lesson that I learned here is that this template could be instantiated into two functions:

```
int compare(const char* &v1, const char* &v2);     // two pointers
int compare(const string &v1, const string &v2);   // two objects
```

Thanks for all the help that you guys offered. Really appreciated! Have a good day!

---

Additional info.

I added a simple express in the myCompare function:

```
cout<<"the type is : "<<typeid(T).name() <<endl;
```

this gives clear type information about what kind of type that T has been instantiated.
the whole code is as following:

```
//----------------------------test.cpp start----------------
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
int myCompare(const T &v1, const T &v2){
    cout<<"the type is : "<<typeid(T).name() <<endl;
    cout<<v1<<" "<<((v1>v2)?(">"):((v1<v2)?("<"):("=")))<<" "<<v2<<endl;
    return (v1>v2)?(1):((v1<v2)?(-1):0);
};

int main(void){
    int iRes;
    iRes=myCompare(1234, 3);
    iRes=myCompare("test","poor");
    iRes=myCompare(static_cast<string>("test"),static_cast<string>("poor"));
    iRes=myCompare(21.23,4.0);
    return 0;
};

//----------------------------test.cpp end----------------
```

this results of this program is:

```
the type is : i
1234 > 3
the type is : A5_c
test > poor
the type is : Ss
test > poor
the type is : d
21.23 > 4
```

Notice that:

```
1, #include <typeinfo> should be included.
2, the second comparison is incorrect, it simply compares the addresses of the constant char array rather than string stored in the constant char array.
```

Hope this would help someone like me who is struggling with templates.

Comment: I know that strcmp() function would work, however, I think the string object has reloaded the relation operator.

Comment: `std::string` yes, but `"A"` isn't a string, it's `const char*`.

Comment: *overloaded operator<

Comment: You're comparing `const char*`s, good job.

Comment: Your version is much less readable than the original, and no more/less efficient. Furthemore, `using namespace std` should be banned.

Comment: The readability suffers a lot from the too many parentheses, not because of the ternary operator.

Comment: You could simplify the body of `compare` to `return (v2 < v1) - (v1 < v2);` Although for expensive comparisons, this would probably be a lot slower than the original in 50 percent of the cases, because both comparisons have to be computed in all cases.

Comment: to ipc, I use vim, the readability is ok, I use those parentheses just in case the output operator associativity gets weired.

Comment: @ipc - yes. **None** of the parentheses in the expression are needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently comparing the values of the pointers, rather than considering `const char *` as a string, which is nearly never what you want. If you want to compare `const char *` as `std::string`s, you should specialise your template.

```
template<>
int myCompare(const char *const &v1, const char *const &v2){
    return myCompare<std::string>(v1, v2);
};
```

Or perhaps, call `strcmp` in that case,

```
template<>
int myCompare(const char *const &v1, const char *const &v2){
    return strcmp(v1, v2);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your code and the original is the type deduced as `T`. In the original, they're passing `std::string` objects into `compare()`. You're passing character literals, which are of type `const char[]`, which decays into `const char*` on template argument deduction.

In other words, your function ends up comparing the literals' addresses, not their contents.

Comment: @GManNickG Thanks for the edit, I was typing a little too quickly.